# Maven Dependency Plugin - Change Output Format of Dependency Tree

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I use `Maven 3.3.9` and the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) version 2.4 to generate a tree of module dependencies in GraphML format. This file shall be imported to a tool such as `yed` to generate a dependency chart.

I use the following command for testing:

`mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=graphml -DoutputFile=dependency.graphml`

The problem I have, is that every node within the file has way too much information for my needs. That makes my charts pretty unreadable.

**What I get as output (this is an example):**

`org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT`

**What I would like to have (this is an example):**

`maven-dependency-plugin`

How can I modify the output format to meet my needs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be helpful to get the current & desired output and to know the purpose (if possible) because `maven` has many features and we could prevent you from "re-inventing the wheel" and save your time.

I've read the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html), it seems they are not exposing interface to exclude/include part of the dependency, best solution so far is using `grep`

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9
```

Outputtype dot is more friendly to for grepping

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=dot
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] digraph "com.a:test:jar:1.0" { 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile" ; 
[INFO]  } 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.215 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-27T17:58:31+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

first `grep` all lines with `>`

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=dot | grep \>
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile" ;
```

Get the strings after `>`

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=dot | grep \> | cut -d\> -f2
 "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" ; 
 "com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile" ; 
 "info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile" ; 
 "log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile" ; 
 "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile" ; 
 "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile" ; 
 "commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile" ; 
 "commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile" ;
```

split the string by colon, get the second match

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=dot | grep \> | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d: -f2
httpclient
gson
picocli
log4j
sqlite-jdbc
httpcore
commons-logging
commons-codec
```

here you go, list of artifacts

## **Update:**

pulling lines between ":tree" and "BUILD SUCCESS"

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | awk '/:tree/,/BUILD SUCCESS/'
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] com.a:test:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] \- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

removing two lines from top (using `awk`) and bottom (using `head`)

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | awk '/:tree/,/BUILD SUCCESS/' | awk 'NR > 2 { print }' | head -n -2
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile
[INFO] +- info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] \- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile
```

pulling relevant lines

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | awk '/:tree/,/BUILD SUCCESS/' | awk 'NR > 2 { print }' | head -n -2 | grep -o -P '.*(?<=:).*(?=:jar)'
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson
[INFO] +- info.picocli:picocli
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j
[INFO] \- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc
```

Removing groupId by removing string between `-` (dash & space) and `:` (colon) using `sed -e 's/\(- \).*\(:\)/\1\2/'`

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | awk '/:tree/,/BUILD SUCCESS/' | awk 'NR > 2 { print }' | head -n -2 | grep -o -P '.*(?<=:).*(?=:jar)' | sed -e 's/\(- \).*\(:\)/\1\2/'
[INFO] +- :httpclient
[INFO] |  +- :httpcore
[INFO] |  +- :commons-logging
[INFO] |  \- :commons-codec
[INFO] +- :gson
[INFO] +- :picocli
[INFO] +- :log4j
[INFO] \- :sqlite-jdbc
```

Removing unneccery colon using `tr`

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | awk '/:tree/,/BUILD SUCCESS/' | awk 'NR > 2 { print }' | head -n -2 | grep -o -P '.*(?<=:).*(?=:jar)' | sed -e 's/\(- \).*\(:\)/\1\2/' | tr -d :
[INFO] +- httpclient
[INFO] |  +- httpcore
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec
[INFO] +- gson
[INFO] +- picocli
[INFO] +- log4j
[INFO] \- sqlite-jdbc
```

## **Update 2:**

Although you completely changed your question, here is a fancy one-liner answer:

```
mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=graphml -DoutputFile=dependency.graphml && python -c "exec(\"from bs4 import BeautifulSoup;bs = BeautifulSoup(open('dependency.graphml'), 'xml')\\nfor e in bs.find_all('NodeLabel'):    e.string = e.string.split(':')[1]\\nprint(bs.prettify())\")" > dependency_fixed.graphml
```

Generate the dependencies tree w/

`mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=graphml -DoutputFile=dependency.graphml`

after it completes (that's why the `&&`) it will execute a python script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bs = BeautifulSoup(open('dependency.graphml'), 'xml')
for e in bs.find_all('NodeLabel'):
    e.string = e.string.split(':')[1]
print(bs.prettify())  # print(bs) will print the minified version
```

which iterates over `NodeLabel` elements, replacing values with the second element of the split by colon result and saving the out into file with `> dependency_fixed.graphml`

Comment: @IdddoE Thx for your answer. I have updated my question and made it more precise. Nevertheless, thanks for your tip regarding grep so far.

Comment: Hi @IddoE Updated my question to illustrate what I would like to achieve in the end.

Comment: Thanks again for your update. It was not my intention to upset you. Will try the Python approach! Keep you posted!

Comment: Your solution works as expected. Many thanks for that. All I had to do was installing `Python 3` and `bs4` and `lxml` using pip install.

Comment: @Iddo thanks, you answer looks helpful. Am stuck with something in similar lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55776695/list-dependencies-of-maven-project-in-desired-format, take a look if you can help.