# List dependencies of maven project in desired format

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-plugin

Am trying to generate dependency tree in maven, making use of below command

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=dot
```

Output looks like below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] digraph "com.a:test:jar:1.0" { 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.9:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" -> "commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile" ; 
[INFO]  } 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It has both direct and transitive dependencies, what i am expecting is just direct one , can making use of `grep` or some flags `-Dexcludes` helps to achieve below output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] digraph "com.a:test:jar:1.0" { 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.2:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "info.picocli:picocli:jar:2.3.0:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile" ; 
[INFO]  "com.a:test:jar:1.0" -> "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:jar:3.21.0:compile" ;
[INFO]  } 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Am expecting something like `npm ls --depth=0` as in node ecosystem, were depth flags helps to just get direct dependencies.

Note: i can't make use of `dependency:list` as i need above structure.

Answer (score 0):

The `maven-dependency-plugin:list` plugin goal provides such a capability with the [`excludeTransitive`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#excludeTransitive) option.
But since you are looking for a *dot* graph output format, you cannot make use of it.

The option would be to programatically parse the output of the `maven-dependency-plugin:tree` output and delete transitive dependencies, i.e. the lines not starting with your module artifact name.

Something basic as the following would work:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree -DoutputType=dot -DoutputFile=out_temp & grep "com.a:test:jar:1.0" out_temp > out_final.gv & echo } >> out_final.gv & rm out_temp
```